# Google Maps app: how to find a shop on a given street (knowing only the shop type)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, maps, google-search

I am using the Google Maps for Android application. I know the name of a street where a certain shop can be found. I don't know the name of the shop, but I know what kind of shop it is (e.g., a book shop), and if I saw the front door to the shop I would be able to figure out it was the one I was looking for.

So, with this task at hand, I open the Google Maps app, enter the name of the street and city name (either by typing it in or by using my voice), and search. I get a red "pin" on the map, pinpointing an arbitrary place on the street I was looking for. At this point I could of course, enter Google Street View and drag the cursor down the street, looking left and right every 5 meters or so, to look for the shop. But the street is long, the process is slow, and it won't always work because the shop entrance may be hidden by a wall separating the sidewalk from the road (perhaps a sequence of stone arches or anything of the like). Besides, the images provided by Street View may not be up-to-date and over time some shop may have turned into a different shop selling a different kind of product.

Here is what I would like Google Maps to do for me:

1. Learn where on the street the lower numbers are found, and where the higher numbers are found. Old cities have streets running in just about any direction, and the direction the numbers increase or decrease is not always intuitive.
2. Provide me with the names of all shops, along with their address and other details (such as the shop type, e.g. bookstore), which can be found along the given street.
3. If (2) is not possible, then the names of all shops which can be reached by a street path of say, no more than a user-specified amount of meters (e.g. 50m, 100m, 200m, 300m, 500m, 1km, 2km, 3km) which must be a user-specified value.
4. In case (2) and/or (3) are possible, then, I would like to know, if a shop wants to appear at a given address in Google Maps, then I've heard it can be done for free by supplying an an address where some snail-mail is received with a code which is then supplied to google to confirm the existence of the shop. If this is true, where is the site where such registration can be done? Also, I've heard that at an extra price Google will also enter the shop and take pictures to post on the Google Maps service (but I haven't seen any of these from my Android device).